# Exception in constructor while creating com object

Tags: c#, com

What exception should I throw if creating com object fails (in my own class instance constructor)? For example I want to create Excel.Application object. If it fails, I want to throw specific Exception with inner exception filled with COMException generated by Excel.Application constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create your own class of exceptions you can, but you don't have to do that to wrap a new exception around an inner exception.

```
public class CustomException : Exception
{
}

public static void main()
{

    try
    {
       //Code that instantiates COM object.

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
       throw new CustomException("This is my message.  I can put anything I want to, then pass the real exception as the inner exception", ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: ANy idea how to name it? InstanceInitializationException or something?

Comment: That's entirely up to you.  No one else will guess what you named it.  If they want to trap your excpetion specifically they will know of it's existence and know what you named it.

Comment: COnstructorFailException? Please help me, and suggest name.

Comment: It's just a name.  Name it.  You wouldn't ask me to name your baby.  Don't ask me to name your code for you.

Comment: You live in USA so you know english better than me. PLease give me that name. Or I will not accept your answer :-)

Comment: COMInitializationException

Comment: Thanks. That's a great name.